# What is <rs: in Flex/Action Script 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I found

```
<rs:Page>
    <mx:Image source="@Embed('image1.jpg')" />
    <mx:Label   x="400" y="40" fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="9" color="#cccccc" text="butn" />
    <mx:Label   left="100" right="120" y="90"  color="#Ffccdd" textAlign="left" text="Label Text" />
</rs:Page>
```

In a mxml file. What does that means?

**Edit: 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:filters="flash.filters.*"
    xmlns:rs="com.mybooks.book.*"
    layout="absolute" 
    backgroundColor="#333333" 
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" 
    viewSourceURL="source/index.html" width="600" height="330">
```

Answer (score 5):

It means that a custom namespace with the prefix `rs` is defined. Look for a definition like this at the beginning of the mxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application 
  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
  xmlns:rs="example.package.name.*"
>
```

see [Using XML namespaces](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/mxml_3.html#180790)

`Page` is a custom component which defined in the `rs` namespace.

In plain ActionScript you would write something like this:

```
import com.mybooks.book.Page;

private function createPage(): void
{
    var page: Page = new Page();
    this.addChild(page);
    var image: Image = new Image();
    // TODO: set image properties 
    page.addChild(image);
    var labelA: Label = new Label();
    // TODO: set labelA properties 
    page.addChild(labelA);
    var labelB: Label = new Label();
    // TODO: set labelB properties 
    page.addChild(labelB);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly happening there?

Comment: What will be the code, when this is in Action Script 3 and Flash IDE?

Comment: @coderex, you should provide the definitions of the namespaces in your example.

Comment: @splash Please check "Edit: 1"

Comment: @splash tanQ, hope this will help me, let me try this. :)

Comment: Do you know how can I load all these(<rs:Page....) informations as XML. So I can load from the XML file. Now its written in MXML file. So I wish to take this information from XML...

Answer (score 1):

The above answers that mentioned "rs" being a custom namespace are correct, but "<rs:Page>" is specific enough that it can also be identified as part of [Ruben Swieringa's Flex book component](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/flex-book-component-beta).  When using the component in a Flex project, the "rs" namespace appears as "xmlns:rs="com.rubenswieringa.book.*" by default, due to the package structure of the component. Furthermore, "<rs:Page>" is  a child of "<rs:Book>".

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:rs="com.mybooks.book.*"

the <rs: is the namespace
```